# Centralized syslog-ng logging on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, logging, syslog

I've managed to successfully switch from syslogd to syslog-ng for my logging.  I would however like to have the syslog-ng box receiving all logs from the all boxes running syslog on the network.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for syslogd it should be straight forward.  On each client, add this line to syslog.conf:

```
*.debug             @syslogng-host
```

This is the way I do it, and I make the syslog-ng host sort and/or throw away there.

Keep in mind that this sends everything -- including login success/failures -- over the wire.  This may not be what you want.

Remember that syslog.conf likes tabs, not spaces.

Answer (score 6):

With syslog-ng, you want to add a destination to /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

```
destination loghost {
    tcp("your.hostname.goes.here" port(514));
};
```

You then need a log rule. Something along the lines of this should work.

```
log{
    source(s_all);
    destination(loghost);
};
```

You'll probably need to change s_all to whatever is defined in your syslog-ng.conf as the general source for logs. You'll then need to add a line like this to your standard log source on your log collecter.

```
tcp();
```

Comment: I'd vote up if I could but my rep is till low...thnx Cian.